# Java paint Buffering/disappearing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, paintcomponent

I'am currently creating a program for school and I have 3 problems:
1-  when I add my paint method the stopwatch disappears
2- The method that paints the circle dosen't allow me to move it with the arrow keys after adding the paint method.
3- This isn't a problem, but when I remove the paint method the circle moves fine with the arrow keys and the clock shows up as I want it
The main thing I want to know is why the paint method is causing problems in my program.
Below is the code.

```
public class Mov extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
static JFrame window = new JFrame();
static JLabel clockLabel = new JLabel();
static int Add = 0;
static SimpleDateFormat clock = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm:ss");
public static Date lastDate = new Date();
Random random = new Random();

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Date hour = new Date();
Toolkit toolkit;
Timer timer;
Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
int x = 600, y = 200, velX = 0, velY = 0;


public void paint(Graphics e) {
int xpoints[] = {35, 50, 25};
int ypoints[] = {50, 100, 100};
int npoints = 3;
xpoints[0] = random(0, 1215);
xpoints[1] = random(0, 1215);
xpoints[2] = random(0, 1215);
ypoints[0] = random(0, 635);
ypoints[1] = random(0, 635);
ypoints[2] = random(0, 635);
Date dateNow = new Date();
// in milliseconds
long diff = dateNow.getTime() - lastDate.getTime();
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
if (diffSeconds > 5) { 
lastDate = new Date(); 
paintComponent(e);
e.setColor(Color.RED);
e.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);
} 
}



public void show(){
   Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
```

`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
   c1.set(1995, 5, 25, 0, 0, Add++);
   Date hour = c1.getTime();
   clockLabel.setText(clock.format(hour));
   clockLabel.repaint();
   }
   });
   timer.start();
   }

public Mov(){
tm.start();
addKeyListener(this);
setFocusable(true);
setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}



public void paintComponent(Graphics p) {
setDoubleBuffered(false);
super.paintComponent(p);
p.setColor(Color.GRAY);
p.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
if(x>1215){
x = 1215;
}
if(x<0){
x = 0;
}
if(y<0){
y = 0;
}
if(y>630){
y = 630;
}
}



 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
 x = x + velX;
 y = y + velY;
 x += velX;
 y += velY;
 x += velX;
 y += velY;
 x += velX;
 y += velY;
 repaint();
 }







public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
velX = 0;
velY = 0;
}



 public static void main(String[]args){
    Mov panel2 = new Mov();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(window.getContentPane(), 
    BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel2.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel2.add(clockLabel);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.pack();
    window.add(panel2);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      App app = new App();
      app.show();
    }  
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: *The main thing I want to know is why the paint method is causing problems in my program.* - You should NOT be overriding paint() and you should NOT invoke paintComponent() from the paint() method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).  for an example of the proper way to do custom painting. Start with the working example and replace that painting code with your painting code so you start with a better structured class. Once the painting works then you worry about your animation.

Comment: `setDoubleBuffered(false);` is a bad idea generally and certainly shouldn't be called from within `paintComponent`

Comment: If you want absolute control over the paint process, you will need to make use of a `BufferStrategy` instead

Comment: `java.util.Date` and it's associated classes are effectively deprecated and you should make the effort to avoid them.  I would also reconsider updating the "clock" every 40 milliseconds, 500 milliseconds would be a more efficient and give a decent result, but, having said that, you might consider making use of a single update loop instead.  You should also avoid using `KeyListener`, for a litany of reasons, and instead make use of the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

Comment: I appreciate the advice